# Нужна ли прописная в поздравлении "С наступающим!"

Tags: прописная-строчная

Когда пишут просто "С наступающим!" - не должно ли "наступающим" писаться с прописной из-за того, что вбирает в этом случае значение "наступающим Новым годом"?

Answer (score 2):

В письменной речи такое поздравительное восклицание может либо отображать устную *недоговорку* (при передаче прямой речи - там даже местоимение "вы" не пишется с большой), либо упрощённо дополнять ранее упомянутое событие или название праздника, *не подменяя* его названия (*Завтра уже Новый год. Так что с наступающим тебя!*) В обоих случаях нет оснований начинать это слово с заглавной буквы. То же самое касается беседы в чате - это аналог устной речи с её упрощениями, которые могут опираться на содержание реплики собеседника ( *- Завтра я отмечаю День шахтёра. - Тогда с наступающим!*) и даже на подразумеваемое обеими сторонами событие.

Answer (score 0):

Тут скорее с наступающим [праздником], ведь и такое может быть: "Да с хорошей погодой! Да с наступающим праздником! Да с чёрствыми именинами! [Н. А. Тэффи. Покаянное (1910)]" (речь идет о предпасхальных днях). Обратите внимание, что, каждый раз говоря "с наступающим", вы не твердите про себя: сейчас я имею в виду Новый год, а сейчас – День ВМФ.

*С наступающим* – это такая универсальная формула, применимая не только к Новому году или Рождеству. Например, могут поздравлять с наступающим **д**нем **р**ождения. Поэтому и прописной буквы здесь быть не может

Comment: Спасибо, конечно, но никогда не встречал "С наступающим" в смысле дня рождения:)

Comment: @Владимир однако есть немало таких примеров :) хотя ваше удивление понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то надуманный вопрос, простите.
С заглавной пишутся имена собственные, иногда - слова, приближающиеся с собственным по функционалу, выступающие в роли неких условно-собственных имен. Последний случай - вообще штука довольно тонкая, единственный безусловный пример - текст в официальном документе наподобие "далее именуемые ***Сторонами***".

"Наступающий" - некое обозначение праздника, свойство, эпитет даже, но никак не **название**, хотя бы условное. Напишите "С наступающим праздником" - вам же не захочется слово "праздник" писать с заглавной? Хотя тут-то еще можно притянуть (с большим треском) обоснование, что это какое-то "условное" имя собственное.

Так что я просто мотивации не вижу для заглавной. А посему подробное обоснование "почему не заглавная" кажется мне излишним.